# Modeling error structure in lmer in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Is it possible to add a parameter to `lmer` model which will be modeling the error structure? Sth similar to TOEP(X) and SP(POW) from SAS???

Comment: I don't think so, but Ben Bolker might correct me. However, covariance structures can be specified with `lme` from the nlme package. See also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49793/11849

Comment: For future reference and for the SAS-impaired, it would be nice to describe what `TOEP(X)` and `SP(POW)` statements actually do (I'm guessing a Toeplitz structure and some kind of spatial power autocorrelation function)?

Comment: As you wrote Ben Bolker. The first one is Toeplitz and the second is spatial power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such parameter. However, you could try `nlme` library, the ancestor of `lmer`. `nlme` library enables you to define a [correlation structure](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/corClasses.html), e.g. [Gaussian](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/corGaus.html), Autoregressive, or [ARMA](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/corARMA.html).

For detailed description, tutorial and examples check this book:
Pinheiro, J.C., and Bates, D.M. (2000). *Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS*. Springer.

You can also find some examples [here](http://stat.bell-labs.com/NLME/UGuide.pdf) and [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/spatial_regression.htm).

Comment: Why would the ancestor be more powerful than the latest ? Is this a choice or is this pending ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel don't ask me about the decisions made by the designers of both packages...