# Complex level 1 variance mixed effects models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, modeling, residuals, lme4-nlme

Take this mixed effects model in R:

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{ij} + u_{j} + e_{ij}$

where $u$ is a random effect (level 2 residual) with groups $j$. It is possible to allow the variance of $e_{ij}$ (level 1 residuals) to be a function of $X$. This could potentially result in a 'fanning out' or 'fanning in' of level 1 residuals within each group $j$.

Is it possible to implement this 'complex level 1 variance' mixed effects model in R? Does `lme4` allow it?

(Stack Overflow doesnt appear to allow LaTeX formatting of mode formula so I've asked this question here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lme4` does not offer possibility to model variance components, however it is possible with `nlme` package, where you can define [different variance functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/varClasses.html). Check also this answer and the references: [Modeling error structure in lmer in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129290/modeling-error-structure-in-lmer-in-r/129292#129292)

Comment: Why is this feature implemented in an older version of lme but not a newer version?

Comment: `nlme` is not older version of `lme4`, I don't know why it was not implemented in `lme4` - you could ask the authors.