# Intra-individual covariance matrix in lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I wonder, why do not need to specify the structure of the variance covariance matrix and the lmer function library lme4, since using the lm function library nlme this is possible.
Thank you.

Comment: Is your question about specifying/imposing a specific variance-covariance structure in `lme4` (as opposed to `nlme`)? Did you read this [related thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models/5345#5345)?

Comment: My question is for what reason does not specify to individual intra covariance structure in lme4.

Comment: I think [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49775/930)  (and many more via Google) addresses your question, then.